# Targeting HTML ID's and using jQuery to modify the content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this photo switcher below that I want to modify the HTML content using jQuery only. If you click on the "Show Next Photo" link jQuery will replace the  "fruits.png" with another image example "airplane.png". (note: No changes to the HTML block is allowed).

I'm not sure how complicated it can be for jQuery. If I could avoid JavaScript, would be perfect.

```
<!--Do Not Change Inside this DIV-->
    <div id="imageSwitcher">
        <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/fruits.png" id="fruits" />
        <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/tulips.png" id="tulips" style="display:none;" />
        <p><a href="#">Show Next Photo</a></p>
    </div>
```

**Problem:**
This is my script below and isn't working properly because when I refresh the page it just shows the airplane.png, and if I click on the link "Show Next Photo" it makes the airplane disapear.

**Please give it a try at https://codepen.io/mrborges/pen/QQjJOq**

```
<script>
        //Go away fruits.png
        document.getElementById('fruits').style.cssText = "display:none;";

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('p').click(function () {
                $('#imageSwitcher img').attr("src", "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png");
                //$('#fruits').toggle("hide");
                $('#tulips').toggle("slow");


            })
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        let count = localStorage.getItem('count') || 0; // "0, 1, 2" or 0
        count = parseInt(count, 10); //If we get it from storage then convert to number
        const images = [
            "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/fruits.png",
            "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/tulips.png",
            "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png"
        ];
        $('#fruits').attr("src", images[count]);

        $('p').click(function () {
            count = (count + 1) % images.length;
            $('#fruits').attr("src", images[count]);
            localStorage.setItem('count', count);
        });
    });
</script>
```

The `const images` is a list (array) of links to the switch between. I added all the possible images and then i just change the src for each image. a pure jQuery solution would be very ugly, so you have to accept some vanilla JavaScript.

this line `count = (count + 1) % images.length` counts 1 up each time you click on the `<p>` if we reach the end of the images, then it just resets to `0`. e.g. `(2 + 1) % 3 = 0`

Comment: I really appreciate your time and knowledge. It's working now. Based on your script, which level would you classify your answer/knowledge? Thank you so much.

Comment: Very basic. In the beginning it is great to see how others have made it, and then try to replicate or change one thing to see what happens. All these words that are being thrown around just makes everything more confusing. Knowledge wise, i would say expert, i would rewrite you program because it isn't "smart", but that's what i am here for.

Comment: Hi Pavlo, the script works right but when I combine with the original HTML block the results are not right. Like I mentioned earlier, I cannot change anything inside of the HTML block. It shouldn't show the fruits.png image first when I load/refresh the page, this specific image fruits.png have to disappear. Could you take a look again? Thank you

Comment: Your original HTML is incomplete. You need to explain why it NEEDS to have that structure. Basically you have two images, and you just hiding one of the images, then changing the src of the other image, why do you need the other image in the first place?

Comment: The original HTML is a locked file and I cannot change it. I was trying to use  JavaScript or jQuery to modify the content without touching the original HTML. Do you think is possible?

Comment: Yes everything is possible, its just a sub-optimal solution

Comment: Do you have any idea which pictures you want to show?

Comment: Very interesting seeing the transition to the last updated code. It's working now. Thank you Pavlo for taking your time and effort. Based on your updated script, which level would you classify your code?

Comment: 3/10 i would say, but its really hard to compare though